# response para descargar archivo .bib en Django Rest Framework. Python

Tags: python, archivo, djangorestframework, response

tengo que generar un archivo `.bib` Lo hago en django rest framework, para ello en diferentes archivos como csv he ocupado lo siguiente.

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv') 
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'
```

La cuestión es que he estado buscando como hacer un response para la descarga de un archivo `.bib` pero no logro encontrar que va en el `content_type` Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de probar varias cosas, logré encontrar la solución, el response para un archivo `bibtex` es este:

```
response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='text/x-bibtex')  
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.bib"'
```